# Line break at a whitespace in inline code listing

Tags: listings

How can I automatically break the following inline code at a whitespace?

**The problem is that I have to use `breaklines=false`**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lstset{breaklines=false,
        literate={,}{}{0\discretionary{,}{}{,}}}

\begin{document}
\lstinline{ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC}\\
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**edit**

I adapt the `literate` parameter from another example but it doesn't work with spaces.

Comment: You could use `\lstinline[breaklines=true]{ABC, ABC ...}` for the one case where you actually want to break the lines.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thx, maybe there is a solution using literate.

Comment: You can always `\newcommand{\lstinlinebrk}{\lstinline[breaklines=true]}` and then use `\lstinlinebrk{ABC, ABC, ...}`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
literate={\ }{}{0\discretionary{}{}{\mbox{ }}}
```

but it's better to insert the `\lstinline` in a `sloppypar` environment to avoid the text going beyond the margins.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lstset{breaklines=false,
        literate={\ }{}{0\discretionary{}{}{\mbox{ }}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\lstinline{ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC}
\end{sloppypar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Anyway, I wonder why you can't use the options

```
breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true
```

for the specific `\lstinline`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I need breaklines=false because I specify other line breaks than ', ' manually. If breaklines=true listings makes mistakes separating words.